# Getting onFocusChange callback for Buttons in SwiftUI (tvOS)

Tags: swiftui, focus, tvos, focus-engine

The `onFocusChange` closure in the `focusable(_:onFocusChange:)` modifier allows me to set properties for the parent view when child views are focused, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
            Text("top")
                .padding()
                .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focused in
                    text = "top focus"
                })
            Text("bottom")
                .padding()
                .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focused in
                    text = "bottom focus"
                })
        }
        
    }
}
```

But in the 2020 WWDC video where `focusable` is introduced, it is clearly stated that this wrapper in not intended to be used with intrinsically focusable views such as Buttons and Lists.  If I use Button in place of Text here the onFocusChange works, but the normal focus behaviour for the Buttons breaks:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
            Button("top") {}
                .padding()
                .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focused in
                    text = "top focus"
                })
            Button("bottom") {}
                .padding()
                .focusable(true, onFocusChange: { focused in
                    text = "bottom focus"
                })
        }
        
    }
}
```

Is there any general way to get an onFocusChange closure to use with Buttons that doesn't break their normal focusable behaviour?  Or is there some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63172333/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi, Unfortunately, no. With @Environment(\.isFocused) var focused: Bool, I can declaratively modify how views appear, i.e. with ternary conditionals, but this doesn't provide any way to assign a value or execute code based focus change.

Comment: Try using the .isFocused environment value with .onChange(of:perform:) to execute code. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/onchange(of:perform:)

Comment: @Adam, thank you! .onChange(of:perform:) with .isFocused environment value gives me the callback I needed.  If you have the chance, please add this as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `@Environment(\.isFocused)` and `.onChange(of:perform:)` in a ButtonStyle:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
          Button("top") {
             // button action
          }
          .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
    }
}

struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Environment(\.isFocused) var focused: Bool

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .onChange(of: focused) { newValue in
                // do whatever based on focus
            }
    }
}
```

IIRC using `@Environment(\.isFocused)` inside a ButtonStyle may only work on iOS 14.5+, but you could create a custom View instead of a ButtonStyle to support older versions.